# Multi-parameter log likelihood of Normal distribution for two separate samples

Tags: self-study, likelihood

I have been given two sets of independent random variables distributed by two different normal distributions $X_1,...,X_n \sim N(\theta_1,1)$ and $Y_1,...,Y_m \sim N(\theta_2,1)$. And have been asked to find the log likelihood function for the parameter $\theta = (\theta_1,\theta_2)$. I was wondering if a correct approach would be to have $l(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n(log(f(\theta_1;x_i)) + \sum_{i=1}^m(log(f(\theta_2;y_i)))$, where $f(\theta_1;x_i)$ is the pdf for $X_i \sim N(\theta_1,1)$ or am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: yes. The reason is: the independence of the observations allows you to write their joint density as the product of the corresponding marginal densities. The result follows by taking the $\log()$ of this and by using the properties of the logarithm.